# a performace issue of mybatis 3.5.3

Tags: mybatis

My team meet a performance issue of mybatis 3.5.3, execute a simple select from mysql which takes about 15 seconds. The result of this query is a List, and the count of the list is 150. The mapper is as follow:

```
<select id = 'selectMapList' reusltMap='mainMap'>
      select #90 properties# from table where #condition#
</select>

<resultMap id = 'mainMap' type='java.util.Map'>
      #90 <result> labels #
</resultMap>
```

But when I update the version to 3.5.4, it works fine. I have traced the source code and found DefaultResultSetHandler#handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap cost too much time, but I can't found the root cause of this scenario. Could somebody help me about this? thx.

Comment: For 3.5.3 and 3.5.4,  do you have any detail SQL level log? 
The detail log can help reveal the latency of the related processing.

Comment: @SeanH I monitor the execution duration of the sql, about 300 ms